# How to conditionally strikethrough text in table rows?

Tags: php, css, conditional-statements, strikethrough

I wanto strikethrough text in rows when the option "ANL" is selected. The colour style is working great, but when I add `text-decoration:line-through`, all of table has strikethrough text.

Any ideas what is wrong?

```html
$colorMap = [
    "ANL" => 'grey',
    2 => 'red',
    // add more
];

foreach($dane as $s): ?>
    <tr  style=" color:<?php echo $colorMap[$s['nr_d']] ?>;text-decoration:line-through"> 
        
        <form action="uso.php" method="post"> 
            <td ><?=htmlspecialchars($s['id'])?></td>
            <td><?=htmlspecialchars($s['counter'])?> </td>
            <td><?=htmlspecialchars(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($s['data_in'])))?></td>
            <td><?=htmlspecialchars($s['count_mat'])?></td>
            <td><textarea class="small1 noborder" rows="1" cols="20" maxlength="50" name="name_inst"><?=htmlspecialchars($s['name_inst'])?></textarea></td>
            <td><?=htmlspecialchars($s['nr_own'])?></td>
            <td><?=htmlspecialchars($s['data_out'])?></td>
            <td><textarea class="small1 noborder" rows="1" cols="20" maxlength="100" name="info_spr"><?=htmlspecialchars($s['info_spr'])?></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea class="small1 noborder" rows="1" cols="20" maxlength="50" name="count_zal"><?=htmlspecialchars($s['count_zal'])?></textarea></td>
            <td>
                <select class="noborder" name="nr_d" '<?=htmlspecialchars($s['nr_d'])?>'
            </td>"
            >  
                    <option><?=htmlspecialchars($s['nr_d'])?></option>
                    <option>YES</option>
                    <option>NO</option>
                    <option>ANL</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've attached line-thorugh to all `<tr>` not specific one (with ANL attribute)

replace `text-decoration:line-through` with `<?php echo $s['nr_d']=="ANL" && "text-decoration:line-through;" ?>`

or u can replace whole line

```
<tr  style=" color:<?php echo $colorMap[$s['nr_d']] ?>;text-decoration:line-through">
```

with

`<tr  style=" color:<?php echo $colorMap[$s['nr_d']].$s['nr_d']=="ANL" && "text-decoration:line-through; ?>">`